# Track a click on a flash movie (object / embed) with jQuery

Tags: jquery, flash, click, capture

I am making a dynamic banner system which can handle img banners, as well as flash banners done with object/embed. The entire site makes heavy use of jQuery, including handling the 'click' events.

This obviously isn't a problem when it comes to tracking the clicks on the image itself (i track the click on the parent DIV tag. However, it fails when the advert is an SWF, as I suspected it would.

Is there a jQuery workaround that would allow me to capture a click on a Flash element with the DOM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to the source of SWF, you can use `ExternalInterface` to communicate with the containing html page.

```
//inside the flash movie:
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
   ExternalInterface.call("handleFlashClick", [parameters to the method]);
}

//javascript in the containing html page
function handleFlashClick()
{
  //call the jQuery method here.
}
```

Comment: i don't have access to the source at all, it's a banner system that would allow customers to upload their own SWF banners to the system.

With that said, would it be a better idea to link an 'in-house' banner which loads the client banner SWF as a movie within itself, giving my SWF control of the flash file, while still allowing untouched client SWF files to be uploaded??

Answer (score 10):

I know this was posted a long time ago and already answered but I just wanted to add a much easier solution for future site visitors. While the embedded SWF file will swallow the onclick event it does not swallow the onmousedown event. The trick is having the wmode set to transparent in the param tags as well as in the embed tag.

```
<div id="layer1" onmousedown="alert('mouse down')"> 
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
codebase="http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" 
width="799" height="741" id="myMovieName">
<param name="movie" value="_data.swf" /> 
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="play" value="true" />
<param name="loop" value="true" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<embed src="_data.swf" quality=high bgcolor=#FFFFFF width="799" height="741" 
name="myMovieName" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
play="true" loop="true" wmode="transparent"
pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash">
</embed>
</object>
</div>
```

You can use jQuery to bind to the mousedown event instead like so:

```
$('#layer1').mousedown(function() {
  alert('mouse down');
});
```

Comment: any possible way to do the same thing with double click ?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to take webwires answer and get an object click working using the following.

```
// Podcast player GA event tracking
var podcast_player = $('object.podcast-player');
if( podcast_player.length > 0 )
{
    podcast_player.live('mousedown',function(){
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Podcast', 'Play']);
    });
}
```

I hope this helps someone else out there, thanks **webwires**.