# jQuery detect click inside a div

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jQuery to detect when a user clicks inside a div on a page. Should be easy enough, but it's not working.

Here's a summary of my code (in the HTML):

```
<div class="outerDiv">
    <object id="video">
      ...
     </object>
</div>
```

In the jQuery:

```
$("body").on("click",function(e){
if(e.target.id=="outerDiv") {
   ... do something
}           
if(e.target.id=="video") {
    alert("Inside div");
}
 ...

});
```

However, when clicking inside the object with the id of "video", nothing happens. But if I click inside "outerDiv", this is picked up by the code.

Could it be beacse inside the "video" id I have an object (in this case a built in flash video player)?

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers :) .

Comment: do you mean `e.target.id=="video"`?  instead of flash_holder .. if not where is flash_holder

Comment: You might take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789233/track-a-click-on-a-flash-movie-object-embed-with-jquery

Comment: Also.. your outerDiv is a class in your html but you are checking for id

Comment: check out "target" in the jquery documentation.

Comment: Seems to work here (http://jsfiddle.net/gMWz9/) if you click on the flash.

Comment: @ComputerArts what browser are you using?  If I'm clicking inside the flash video there are no alerts.. but if I click outside the video and inside the div it alerts - IE9/FF15/Chrome22.0.1229.92

Comment: @wirey Weird, I'm using FF 15.0.1 and I get the alert box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the *inner* click event is processed by Flash. Such click isn't propagated out to your DOM element unless you implement it within the SWF file manually..

Comment: How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/gMWz9/ Click on the flash and the alert will go off.

Comment: Really? It doesn't work for me (tried Chrome & IE).. Could that be somehow enabled in Flash settings?

Comment: @MichalKlouda That's nailed it, thanks for that, it explains a lot. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 7):

Why not target the specific div by adding another parameter to the 'on' call?

```
$("body").on("click", "#flash_holder", function(e) {
   alert("clicked on flash_holder");
});
```

if you are only targeting a single element, probably don't need to use delegation at all:

```
$("#flash_holder").click(function(e) {
   alert("clicked on flash_holder");
});
```