# .click event don't work on a certain div ID conflict?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to execute a function when I click on a specific div ID and nothing happens, help! Example:

```
$( "#jwplayer-1_wrapper" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler Clicked" );
});
```

[-> Full example here <-](http://jsfiddle.net/2mK7Z/)

Comment: Select `jquery` as framework from left pannel. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2mK7Z/7/)

Comment: I don't think you can catch clicks on flash movies :)

Comment: @onetrickpony he's not binding events to flash object. `div` has wrap the `object` element so you can bind events to it.

Comment: I am pretty sure the flash punches a hole in the div

Comment: Yeah, any click on the div, is actually a click on the flash movie. But I guess he could absolutely position some kind of transparent DIV on top of the flash, with higher z-index

Comment: @onetrickpony of course with `position: absolute` with higher `z-index` it is possible to bind events

Comment: yes but since its not my webpage i would have to inject it... and i dont think its what will resolve my problem, tough thanks for letting me know its the flash plug in that troubles the rest

Comment: @Rahil Wazir How could I do that only with javascript?

Comment: @SamuelCharpentier, your Fiddle works so long as you've loaded jQuery. My answer below demonstrates how this can be accomplished from the Google CDN.

Comment: @SamuelCharpentier See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2mK7Z/18/) updated fiddle only with javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this

http://jsfiddle.net/2mK7Z/22/

```
$(document).ready(function(event)
{
    $('#jwplayer-1_wrapper').mousedown(function() {
      alert('click detetced');
    });
});
```

Comment: Using the 'mousedown' did the trick for me instead of using click

Comment: This works but only if i inject the code manualy after the whole page is loaded, how can I delay it to when the flash element has loaded completly?

Comment: did you try it with $('#jwplayer-1_wrapper').on('mousedown',function() {
      alert('click detetced');
    });

Comment: Yes but it need to be injected manualy (since im working with an injector and I dont choose when the script is loaded (probably 1st script executed)) and it needs to load before it can execute itself

Comment: If you use 'on' , it should fire no matter when it is injected. It's 4:30 in the morning here , I should try getting some sleep . I don't have anything to test here either , will try it in the morning .

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the problem you are experiencing: [Track a click on a flash movie (object / embed) with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789233/track-a-click-on-a-flash-movie-object-embed-with-jquery)

That is - the embedded flash object steals the click event, and jquery will never see it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you create the element dynamically? It could be that the element doesn't exist at document ready. Try:

```
$("body").on("click", "#jwplayer-1_wrapper", function() {
  alert("Handler clicked");
})
```

Otherwise, check the ID and make sure it's correct.

Comment: No he does not. The click also does not work in the fiddle after setting onload

Answer (score -1):

You have to wait for the DOM to become ready. Use jQuery(document).ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $( "#jwplayer-1_wrapper" ).click(function() {
     alert( "Handler Clicked" );
   });
});
```

Comment: It would make sens, but its not changing any thing, i clic on it on the original full site and it still dont alert me (I'm using this script in a stript injector for chrome)

Comment: The jQuery(document).ready runs when the page load, so, editing the loaded script won't work, bcuz the page has already loaded