# Add a class to body when play is pressed on a Vimeo embed

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, embed, vimeo

I could really use some help on this one. 
I need to add a class to the body tag when someone presses the play button on a Vimeo embed.

The background on the site is white and when someone presses the play button, a class is added to the body tag so the background fades to black (body class="bgcolor_black").
And when the movie is paused or stops it goes back to the white background (body class="bgcolor_white").

Is this possible? The site is built on Wordpress.
I have searched alot but all I can find is about a extra button to "turn the lights off".

Thanks in advance and sorry if the english is bad :)

Comment: Not sure if this helps and by no way this is an answer to your question, but, just a guidance.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789233/track-a-click-on-a-flash-movie-object-embed-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done unless vimeo.com allows your domain to execute cross-domain interaction. It is not allowed for security reasons. This security measure is known as the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me and thanks Sionnach for this suggestion, it is exactly what im looking for. Unfortunately I didnt get it to work. Theres no action when im pressing the play button on the vimeo movie. I tried to put the code both in the footer.php and the header.php, i also tried putting the "bgcolor_white" as a static class in the body tag (so it had something to remove).

Do you have any idea? I saw somewhere else that I should add "listeners" first. Can that be the problem here? That the script works but cant find the ".play-icon"

Comment: @swedoc my mistake, after doing some more research, I found that it is not possible, see updated answer.

Comment: Ouch! Ok thanks, we have a pro account on Vimeo so maybe they have that option. I update this if I get a answer from Vimeo on the matter.
Have a great week!

Comment: did the pro account grant you access? Consider accepting this answer.

Comment: Yes, I seems that it's possible with the Vimeo API. I couldn't do an follow up, cause the client said no to the feature :/ Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this with jQuery!

http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

If you have trouble with implementing comment this answer!