# how to count clicks on flash banner in site

Tags: javascript, php, flash

I got two swf files. One of them is clickTag enabled, and other is not. I must put them in Wordpress site. I'm using adrotate plugin for banners management. Is there a way to know when the banner is clicked,so that i could changed click counter in adrotate manualy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after some help at the work, i think I've answer. if you change `jQuery("a.gofollow").click` for `jQuery("a.gofollow").mousedown` in adrotate plugin clicktracker.js code, it starts to track clicks on flash banners. More explanation can be found there [Track a click on a flash movie (object / embed) with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789233/track-a-click-on-a-flash-movie-object-embed-with-jquery)